Aligning columns from text within rows in Kotlin using Compose
I'm having a hard time getting the columns of data to align. Basically, I have a column that has multiple rows. I make sure (via padding) that the first column of data in each row is of the same length (30). I'd think that the second column (a date) would then align, but it does not. Note that I would like all the columns to align vertically. The only ones I'm having success on are the first (the name field) and the last (a drop-down list).
Here is an example of the output.

Here is the code I am trying. What is it that I am doing wrong, please?
    @Composable
override fun Content() {
    val navigator = LocalNavigator.currentOrThrow
    val patientRealm = openPatientRealm()
    val patients: RealmResults<Patient> = retrieveAllPatients(patientRealm)

    MaterialTheme {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Text("Insertion Visit History")

            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(bottom = 20.dp),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
            ) {
                Text("Name")
                Text(" Date of visit")
                Text("Total Pellet Amount")
                Text("Pellet Lot number(s)")
            }

            var visitRowDataArray: Array<VisitRowData> = arrayOf()

            for (patient in patients) {
                for (visit in patient.visits) {
                    val visitRowData = VisitRowData()
                    visitRowData.patientFirstName = patient.firstName
                    visitRowData.patientLastName = patient.lastName
                    visitRowData.patientLast4OfSSN = patient.lastFourOfSSN
                    visitRowData.visitDate = convertLongDateToString(visit.visitDate)

                    //Create an array of pellets
                    var pelletArray: Array<Pellet> = arrayOf(Pellet())
                    var lotArray: Array<String> = arrayOf("")

                    Logger.d("Showing pelletsUsed of length " + visit.pelletsUsed.size)

                    for (pellet in visit.pelletsUsed) {
                        pelletArray += pellet
                        lotArray += pellet.lotNumber
                    }

                    visitRowData.pelletsUsed = pelletArray
                    visitRowData.lotNumbers = lotArray

                    visitRowDataArray += visitRowData
                }
            }

            var selectedIndex by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(0) }
            val buttonModifier = Modifier.width(120.dp)

            for (visit in visitRowDataArray) {
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(bottom = 3.dp),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically

                ) {
                    Text(text = visit.getName(),
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(3.dp)
                        ,)

                    Text(text = visit.visitDate,
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(3.dp)
                        ,)

                    Text(text = visit.getTotalPelletAmount().toString(),
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(3.dp)
                        ,)

                    DropdownList(itemArray = visit.getPelletToLotNumberArray(), selectedIndex = selectedIndex, modifier = buttonModifier, onItemClick = { selectedIndex = it})
                }
            }

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))

            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(bottom = 20.dp),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
            ) {
                Button(onClick = {
                    closeGenericRealm(patientRealm)
                    navigator.pop()
                }) {
                    Text("Back")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun DropdownList(itemArray: Array<String>, selectedIndex: Int, modifier: Modifier, onItemClick: (Int) -> Unit) {

    var showDropdown by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(true) }
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {

        // button
        Box(
            modifier = modifier
                .clickable { showDropdown = true },
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            Text(text = itemArray[selectedIndex], modifier = Modifier.padding(3.dp))
        }

        // dropdown list
        Box {
            if (showDropdown) {
                Popup(
                    alignment = Alignment.TopCenter,
                    properties = PopupProperties(
                        // CAN'T FIND THIS PARAM -> excludeFromSystemGesture = true,
                    ),
                    // to dismiss on click outside
                    onDismissRequest = { showDropdown = false }
                ) {

                    Column(
                        modifier = modifier
                            .heightIn(max = 90.dp)
                            .verticalScroll(state = scrollState)
                            .border(width = 1.dp, color = Color.Gray),
                        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                    ) {

                        itemArray.onEachIndexed { index, item ->
                            if (index != 0) {
                                Divider(thickness = 1.dp, color = Color.LightGray)
                            }
                            Box(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .background(Color.Gray)
                                    .fillMaxWidth()
                                    .clickable {
                                        onItemClick(index)
                                        showDropdown = !showDropdown
                                    },
                                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                            ) {
                                Text(text = item)
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Maybe you should consider adding weights to your rows
